# Including extension configuration for a library

Tags: configuration, libraries, manifest

Am I guessing right that `<config>` in manifest file for a Joomla library is not supported? Only for modules, components, templates and plugins?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No (as far as I know), but you can register your lib through a plugin and plugins can have config manifests:

https://docs.joomla.org/Using_own_library_in_your_extensions

I would just load the lib into my component and would set params there.